# How do I rewrite this using React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How would you rewrite this using React Hooks?

```
class UsersList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchUsers();
  }

  renderUsers() {
    return this.props.users.map(user => {
      return <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Here's a big list of users:
        <ul>{this.renderUsers()}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to rewrite with React Hooks, but for some reason I do not get back any users rendered on the screen.

I have tried:

```
const UsersList = ({ users }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, [users]);

  const renderUsers = () => {
    console.log(users);
    return (
      <ul>
        {users.map(user => (
          <li key={user.id}> {user.name} </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  };

  return <div> {renderUsers()}</div>;
```

But I am not getting anything rendered on the screen.
Please point out what is my glaring error?

Comment: If `fetchUsers()` causes the users-prop to update then you might have an infinite loop going. Maybe the effect dependency should be fetchUsers or an empty array instead of users. Also in your class component fetchUsers was a prop. In the function component it's origin is not visible.

Comment: I was rerendering too many times with users, I added fetchUsers as the dependecy.

Answer (score 0):

You've got it almost correct. The easy rule of thumb is that `useEffect` with an empty array `[]` is the same as `componentDidMount`/`componentWillUnmount`, because nothing will change in an empty array and so the function is called only once. Also you have to add `fetchUsers` to the property list of the function definition to have access to it.

```
const UsersList = ({ users, fetchUsers }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

  const renderUsers = () => {
    console.log(users);
    return (
      <ul>
        {users.map(user => (
          <li key={user.id}> {user.name} </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  };

  return <div> {renderUsers()}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you! This is the answer I was looking for. I would upvote but I can't due to my lowly reputation status.

Answer (score 0):

React Hooks tie in to our functional components.  A hook is a function that let’s you tap into a react feature like state or life-cycle methods.
you have to implement the useEffect() inside the functional component that you wanna render. once you fetch the data, you have to to change the state.

```
const renderUsers = () => {
    const [users,setUsers]=useState([]) // initially set to empty array
    useEffect(()=>{
          const fetchedUsers=fetchUsers()
          if(fetchedUsers){
             setUsers(fetchedUsers)}          
},[]) //[] here means fire this func only once
  //now your state set to fetched data
    return (
      <ul>
        {users.map(user => (
          <li key={user.id}> {user.name} </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  };

  return <div> {renderUsers()}</div>;
}
```

Comment: I think this is more complicated than has to be... also why are you introducing useState? There is no useState or this.state in the React Class based component above

Comment: @Aquasar react hooks are used only in functional components. whole point of using hooks is to be able to use lifecycle methods and state inside the functional component. react team announced that future of react will be hooks. i suggest you pay extra attention on hooks

Comment: Okay but in this case I don't want to store the users in any state, I want to simply render it to the screen.